# Optiion Strict and Late binding VB

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, binding, automation

Sorry guys, I CTRL-A my original post.. of course.

It was just simply inquiring about a late binding error I was getting with Option Strict On, which was also creating really odd adverse effects during publishing the console app. Doing the below, thanks to very helpful answers solved my issues.

I would say after getting a better grasp on late and early binding, I can see why people shoot for early, there are a lot of really cool and helpful tools that come with it, and it also seems to really aid in avoiding those crash issues.

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
        Dim document As HTMLDocument
        Dim ele As HTMLInputElement
        ie = New InternetExplorer

```
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate("www.google.com")
    While ie.ReadyState <> 4
    End While

    document = CType(ie.Document, HTMLDocument)

    ele = CType(document.getElementById("lst-ib"), HTMLInputElement)

    ele.value = "test"
```

I hope this can help someone else, as it helped me. You can see we have used early binding in the example :)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the browser? It could be that the [WebBrowser Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms) is what you need.

Comment: Added to what @Andrew Morton said, the webbrowser control is what you need, it has a `Document` property which is of type of `HtmlDocument`. Then that type has a method called `GetElementById`which returns an `HtmlElement`. Right now none of your code will work... Also, you`re using old vb6 leftovers, this is not vb...

Comment: Hmm.. so the code seems to work fine, and has been. Multiple published console apps seem to work really well, up until today. So for example, what you see above currently takes an element's ID, then clicks it. Works fine in all the IE browser automations thus far, could you perhaps show an example of  how you would do a similar task? :)

Comment: Use Visual Studio's _Object Browser_ (View Menu->Object Browser) to discover which interface defines the `Document` property. In the Object Browser, expand the the InternetExploreClass node and then expand the "Base Types" node. Click through the various interfaces until you find `Document`. It is defined on the [IWebBrowser2 Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752116(v=vs.85).aspx).  The [getElementById Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752541(v=vs.85)) is defined on IHTMLDocument3.

Comment: @TnTinMn Now that is cool, had no idea how easy all that was to access :). So it seems to say that document is type object. My navigation was slightly different than you describe. IEClass - then I am able to see document with a little wrench next to it. However, I can tell this is going to be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Codexer Hi and thanks for the advice. I am not sure if that is 100% what I need. Basically, just attempting to interact with a webpage via the IDs of buttons, text boxes, etc. The code does all work, and I get the desired result, the question was really about why it would not run when published the way it does when running out of VS, and I stumbled upon a lot of threads about these types of errors when using late binding, so I put Option Strict on to go through it all, which led me to my OP. So far all these suggestions have not disappointed, and gave me a lot of things to learn. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late-binding is basically accessing a member of an object that the compiler cannot confirm exists at compile time.  The issue there, from what I can gather, is that the `InternetExplorer.Document` property is type `Object` and the `Object` type has no `getElementById` method.  The object that that property refers to at run time may well have that method, but if the compiler cannot confirm that at compile time then that is late-binding.

What you need to do is cast `InternetExplorer.Document` as the actual type that it will be at run time so that the compiler knows at compile time that there is a `getElementById` method.  Note that the object itself actually implements a number of different interfaces so you would need to cast as the interface that has the member you want to access.

Comment: Hey thanks! Could you possibly toss a quick example this way. I always thought this:  Dim objBrowser As InternetExplorer
    objBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer   was an explicit type.

Comment: You're quite right that that is an explicit type. That has got exactly zero to do with the problem. You're not listening to what I'm saying. It's not `objBrowser` that is the issue. You're successfully getting the `Document` property of that object. The issue is the result of that property. It returns an `Object` reference and you're trying to call `getElementById` on that. THAT is the issue. That's what you need to cast. What type do you think `Document` is?

Comment: Thank you for the direction here! I am not actually sure what type document is some sort of htmldocument I suppose, but now you're having me going to find out :). I will comment back when I figure this out, it sounds like your answer is the right one though. Thank you

Comment: okay so I am getting somewhere. If I say for instance write dim document as HTMLDOCUMENT I noticed when I type document'.' VS takes over and goes are you trying to use any of these and it gives me a few options to pick from. What I still am missing, is  "cast InternetExplorer.Document,"

Comment: I guess what I am really asking, and forgive me if this is bad terminology, if I attempt to say okay buttonElem = document.getElementById("someElementId") buttonElem is nothing because I assume there no mention of that IE anywhere, and if I add IE, as you said I get that error on Option strict because ie.document does infact bring an return object ref.

Comment: I told you that you need to cast. Do you know how to cast? If not, go and learn how.

Comment: A little tough on the responses given the venue, but points in the right direction and really knows how to handle an issue. Your answer gives me a much better understanding and allowed me to solve the issue. Appreciate your time!